# redirect user to their profile after log in

Tags: users, redirect, buddypress, profiles

I would like to know How can i redirect users to their profile after they log in to my website.

Right now, when users log in, they get riderected to the home page but i would like for them to get redirected to their respective profile.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function custom_user_login_redirect( redirect_to, $redirect_to_raw, $user ) {
   $redirect_to = bp_loggedin_user_domain();
   return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter('bp_login_redirect','custom_user_login_redirect',10,3);
```

Comment: Thanks @shanebp it didnt work but you have pointed me towards the right way

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wp_authenticate`-hook (see [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_authenticate)) to trigger a function, when a user was successfully logged in and then use `wp_redirect` (see [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)) to bringt him to a specific page.

```
add_action ('wp_authenticate' , 'redirect_to_profile');

function redirect_to_profile() {
   $user_profile_url = 'getthisfromwhereever...';
   wp_redirect($user_profile_url);
   exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @flomei! It didnt work but you have pointed me towards the right way.

Comment: You´re welcome. It would be great if you could post your final answer, so others can learn from how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [BP Login Redirect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-login-redirect)

Plugin description:

> Allows to decide buddypress website admins where their users should
>   land after log in

[image]

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your comments and for your help, i greatly appreciate it.

In the end, i downloaded an app called ultimatemember, in which it allows me to control just about everything with members. 

Its better than buddypress and i recommend it to you if you are tyring to build a community. 

Note- i am not affiliated to the plug in, in any way